# Why are some variables declared on the same line as others, and most are declared on their own line?

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to teach myself JS, and working through trying to build a Blackjack game. I found a site which has a good walkthrough, but quite a lot is confusing me.

Here, they declare Global variables:

```
var deck;
var burnCard;

var dealer;
var player = new Array(maxSplits + 1);
var curPlayerHand, numPlayerHands;

var credits, defaultBet;
var creditsTextNode, defaultTextNode;
```

I know/think you can declare multiple variables on one line, like var x, y;
but I'm not sure why it is being used here for some variables but not for others. Why is not possible to put

```
var = deck, burnCard;
```

for example?

If I've left out anything important please let me know and I'll include it. Thank you.

Comment: There's no reason why that couldn't have also been done. You'd need to ask the author of that example why they chose to do it that way.

Comment: The equals sign does not belong in `var = deck, burnCard;`.

Comment: This question would be more apt for another StackExchange community, possibly Programmers as it has to do with Language Syntax rather than answering an actual programming question.

To actually answer the question, as none of the other comments have: it has to do with debugging. When you explicitly declare each new variable, you can set a debugging breakpoint in the browser on each individual variable. When variables are declared in one line / only with one `var` keyword, only one breakpoint can be set for all of those vars.

Comment: The most common reason for this is to group variables that logically belong together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the JavaScript parser it doesn't matter.

Assume someone did it for aesthetic reasons or they were being inconsistent/lazy.

Lint tools such as [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) and [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) will warn you about these inconsistencies.

Comment: Thank you, sometimes this stuff looks confusing when you're trying to learn!